# Consuming OData from SAP System with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, odata, sap-gateway

I want to consume data in XML format from an SAP System.

To do that, I implemented an OData Service in the SAP System and activated it.

I tested it in my SAP Web IDE and it works.

But now I am developing another project in NetBeans consisting of HTML and JavaScript, and I want to consume the OData Service in that Project.

To reach that goal, I did a lot of research on the internet and read about a few options, but I'm still confused.

**Is `XMLHttpRequest` the thing to achieve it, or is it Apache Olingo, etc.?**

Can anybody please give me a clue which technology to use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Apache Olingo is a framework used to expose an OData service in Java. You already have your OData service, you don't need to touch that.
- Both the SAP Web IDE project and your HTML/JavaScript project in Netbeans are clients of your OData service, that is to say, they both query your OData service for data.
- Both the SAP Web IDE project and your HTML/JavaScript project in Netbeans are frontend projects. They both use HTML/CSS/JS to display the page nicely and perform CRUD operations on the data.
- XMLHttpRequest is an API which can be used in plain JavaScript to send requests. You're probably using it in your SAP Web IDE project to query your OData service. As such, you can use it also in your Netbeans project to query your OData service.

So query your OData service in your Netbeans project the same way you do in your Web IDE project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it brings a little Light in the Dark. 
I think this is what i searched for and because of that i marked it as the correct answer.